# Как сделать карусель адаптивной и под ПК и под смартфон?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, style

Дорогие друзья! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: Есть карусель а изображения на ней разного размера. Высота некоторых изображений больше, и когда они выводятся то это портит вид. Установить постоянное значение height не могу, так как в данном случае в мобильниках будет плохо выводится. С вёрсткой не особо дружу. Посоветуйте как быть. Вот код карусели:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
          @foreach($lastPosts as $key => $last)
            <div class="item @if($key == 0) active @endif">
              <!-- post -->
                                <div class="post post-thumb">
                                    <a class="post-img" href="/{{ $last->category->path }}/post/{{ $last->id }}"><img src="./img/posts/{{ $last->image->name }}" class="img-responsive d-block w-100" alt=""></a>
                                    <div class="post-body">
                                        <div class="post-category">
                                            <a href="/{{ $last->category->path }}">{{ $last->category->name }}</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <h3 class="post-title title-lg"><a href="/{{ $last->category->path }}/post/{{ $last->id }}">{{ $last->title }}</a></h3>
                                        <ul class="post-meta">
                                            <li>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($last->date)->format('d '.$months[date('n')].' Y') }}</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /post -->
            </div>
            @endforeach

          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я впоследнее время юзаю "siema" - крутая карусель, никаких зависимостей и вообще ничего лишнего. Увы в ней не хватает кнопок переключения и кружков-индикаторов, но они легко дописываются в пару строчек. 
А вот бутстраповскую карусель я терпеть не могу, адекватного способа ее адаптировать нет, собственно из-за чего и перешел на siema

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var _carousel = document.querySelector('#carousel');
var _inner = _carousel.getElementsByClassName('-inner')[0];
(function() {
  var _carousel = document.querySelector('#carousel');
  var siema = new Siema({
    selector: _inner,
    duration: 750,
    easing: 'ease-out',
    perPage: { //Адаптивность
      360: 1,
      576: 2,
      768: 3,
      992: 4,
      1200: 5
    },
    startIndex: 0,
    draggable: true,
    multipleDrag: true,
    threshold: 20,
    loop: true,
    rtl: false,
    onInit: function() {
      this.interval = setInterval(function() { //Автоперелистывание
        siema.next();
      }, 7000);
    },
    onChange: function() {
      clearInterval(siema.interval);
      this.interval = setInterval(function() {
        siema.next();
      }, 7000);
    },
    interval: null
  });
  //Кнопки влево, вправо
  _carousel.querySelectorAll('.-arrow._left')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    siema.prev();
  });

  _carousel.querySelectorAll('.-arrow._right')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    siema.next();
  });
  //Точки для быстрого перехода
  Siema.prototype.addPagination = function() {
    var f = function(i) {
      var _this = this;
      var btn = document.createElement('button');
      btn.classList.add('-dot');
      btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        _this.goTo(i);
        [].forEach.call(this.parentNode.childNodes, function(el) {
          el.classList.remove('_active');
        });
        this.classList.add('_active');
      });
      this.selector.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('-dots')[0].appendChild(btn);
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < this.innerElements.length; i++) {
      f.call(this, i);
    }
  };
  siema.addPagination();
})();
};

        //LIBRARY CODE
        ! function(e, t) {
           "object" == typeof exports && "object" == typeof module ? module.exports = t() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define("Siema", [], t) : "object" == typeof exports ? exports.Siema = t() : e.Siema = t()
         }("undefined" != typeof self ? self : this, function() {
           return function(e) {
             function t(r) {
               if (i[r]) return i[r].exports;
               var n = i[r] = {
                 i: r,
                 l: !1,
                 exports: {}
               };
               return e[r].call(n.exports, n, n.exports, t), n.l = !0, n.exports
             }
             var i = {};
             return t.m = e, t.c = i, t.d = function(e, i, r) {
               t.o(e, i) || Object.defineProperty(e, i, {
                 configurable: !1,
                 enumerable: !0,
                 get: r
               })
             }, t.n = function(e) {
               var i = e && e.__esModule ? function() {
                 return e.default
               } : function() {
                 return e
               };
               return t.d(i, "a", i), i
             }, t.o = function(e, t) {
               return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t)
             }, t.p = "", t(t.s = 0)
           }([function(e, t, i) {
             "use strict";

             function r(e, t) {
               if (!(e instanceof t)) throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")
             }
             Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {
               value: !0
             });
             var n = "function" == typeof Symbol && "symbol" == typeof Symbol.iterator ? function(e) {
                 return typeof e
               } : function(e) {
                 return e && "function" == typeof Symbol && e.constructor === Symbol && e !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof e
               },
               s = function() {
                 function e(e, t) {
                   for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
                     var r = t[i];
                     r.enumerable = r.enumerable || !1, r.configurable = !0, "value" in r && (r.writable = !0), Object.defineProperty(e, r.key, r)
                   }
                 }
                 return function(t, i, r) {
                   return i && e(t.prototype, i), r && e(t, r), t
                 }
               }(),
               l = function() {
                 function e(t) {
                   var i = this;
                   if (r(this, e), this.config = e.mergeSettings(t), this.selector = "string" == typeof this.config.selector ? document.querySelector(this.config.selector) : this.config.selector, null === this.selector) throw new Error("Something wrong with your selector ");
                   this.resolveSlidesNumber(), this.selectorWidth = this.selector.offsetWidth, this.innerElements = [].slice.call(this.selector.children), this.currentSlide = this.config.loop ? this.config.startIndex % this.innerElements.length : Math.max(0, Math.min(this.config.startIndex, this.innerElements.length - this.perPage)), this.transformProperty = e.webkitOrNot(), ["resizeHandler", "touchstartHandler", "touchendHandler", "touchmoveHandler", "mousedownHandler", "mouseupHandler", "mouseleaveHandler", "mousemoveHandler", "clickHandler"].forEach(function(e) {
                     i[e] = i[e].bind(i)
                   }), this.init()
                 }
                 return s(e, [{
                   key: "attachEvents",
                   value: function() {
                     window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeHandler), this.config.draggable && (this.pointerDown = !1, this.drag = {
                       startX: 0,
                       endX: 0,
                       startY: 0,
                       letItGo: null,
                       preventClick: !1
                     }, this.selector.addEventListener("touchstart", this.touchstartHandler), this.selector.addEventListener("touchend", this.touchendHandler), this.selector.addEventListener("touchmove", this.touchmoveHandler), this.selector.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mousedownHandler), this.selector.addEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseupHandler), this.selector.addEventListener("mouseleave", this.mouseleaveHandler), this.selector.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mousemoveHandler), this.selector.addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler))
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "detachEvents",
                   value: function() {
                     window.removeEventListener("resize", this.resizeHandler), this.selector.removeEventListener("touchstart", this.touchstartHandler), this.selector.removeEventListener("touchend", this.touchendHandler), this.selector.removeEventListener("touchmove", this.touchmoveHandler), this.selector.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.mousedownHandler), this.selector.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseupHandler), this.selector.removeEventListener("mouseleave", this.mouseleaveHandler), this.selector.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.mousemoveHandler), this.selector.removeEventListener("click", this.clickHandler)
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "init",
                   value: function() {
                     this.attachEvents(), this.selector.style.overflow = "hidden", this.selector.style.direction = this.config.rtl ? "rtl" : "ltr", this.buildSliderFrame(), this.config.onInit.call(this)
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "buildSliderFrame",
                   value: function() {
                     var e = this.selectorWidth / this.perPage,
                       t = this.config.loop ? this.innerElements.length + 2 * this.perPage : this.innerElements.length;
                     this.sliderFrame = document.createElement("div"), this.sliderFrame.style.width = e * t + "px", this.enableTransition(), this.config.draggable && (this.selector.style.cursor = "-webkit-grab");
                     var i = document.createDocumentFragment();
                     if (this.config.loop)
                       for (var r = this.innerElements.length - this.perPage; r < this.innerElements.length; r++) {
                         var n = this.buildSliderFrameItem(this.innerElements[r].cloneNode(!0));
                         i.appendChild(n)
                       }
                     for (var s = 0; s < this.innerElements.length; s++) {
                       var l = this.buildSliderFrameItem(this.innerElements[s]);
                       i.appendChild(l)
                     }
                     if (this.config.loop)
                       for (var o = 0; o < this.perPage; o++) {
                         var a = this.buildSliderFrameItem(this.innerElements[o].cloneNode(!0));
                         i.appendChild(a)
                       }
                     this.sliderFrame.appendChild(i), this.selector.innerHTML = "", this.selector.appendChild(this.sliderFrame), this.slideToCurrent()
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "buildSliderFrameItem",
                   value: function(e) {
                     var t = document.createElement("div");
                     return t.style.cssFloat = this.config.rtl ? "right" : "left", t.style.float = this.config.rtl ? "right" : "left", t.style.width = (this.config.loop ? 100 / (this.innerElements.length + 2 * this.perPage) : 100 / this.innerElements.length) + "%", t.appendChild(e), t
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "resolveSlidesNumber",
                   value: function() {
                     if ("number" == typeof this.config.perPage) this.perPage = this.config.perPage;
                     else if ("object" === n(this.config.perPage)) {
                       this.perPage = 1;
                       for (var e in this.config.perPage) window.innerWidth >= e && (this.perPage = this.config.perPage[e])
                     }
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "prev",
                   value: function() {
                     var e = arguments.length > 0 && void 0 !== arguments[0] ? arguments[0] : 1,
                       t = arguments[1];
                     if (!(this.innerElements.length <= this.perPage)) {
                       var i = this.currentSlide;
                       if (this.config.loop) {
                         if (this.currentSlide - e < 0) {
                           this.disableTransition();
                           var r = this.currentSlide + this.innerElements.length,
                             n = this.perPage,
                             s = r + n,
                             l = (this.config.rtl ? 1 : -1) * s * (this.selectorWidth / this.perPage),
                             o = this.config.draggable ? this.drag.endX - this.drag.startX : 0;
                           this.sliderFrame.style[this.transformProperty] = "translate3d(" + (l + o) + "px, 0, 0)", this.currentSlide = r - e
                         } else this.currentSlide = this.currentSlide - e
                       } else this.currentSlide = Math.max(this.currentSlide - e, 0);
                       i !== this.currentSlide && (this.slideToCurrent(this.config.loop), this.config.onChange.call(this), t && t.call(this))
                     }
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "next",
                   value: function() {
                     var e = arguments.length > 0 && void 0 !== arguments[0] ? arguments[0] : 1,
                       t = arguments[1];
                     if (!(this.innerElements.length <= this.perPage)) {
                       var i = this.currentSlide;
                       if (this.config.loop) {
                         if (this.currentSlide + e > this.innerElements.length - this.perPage) {
                           this.disableTransition();
                           var r = this.currentSlide - this.innerElements.length,
                             n = this.perPage,
                             s = r + n,
                             l = (this.config.rtl ? 1 : -1) * s * (this.selectorWidth / this.perPage),
                             o = this.config.draggable ? this.drag.endX - this.drag.startX : 0;
                           this.sliderFrame.style[this.transformProperty] = "translate3d(" + (l + o) + "px, 0, 0)", this.currentSlide = r + e
                         } else this.currentSlide = this.currentSlide + e
                       } else this.currentSlide = Math.min(this.currentSlide + e, this.innerElements.length - this.perPage);
                       i !== this.currentSlide && (this.slideToCurrent(this.config.loop), this.config.onChange.call(this), t && t.call(this))
                     }
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "disableTransition",
                   value: function() {
                     this.sliderFrame.style.webkitTransition = "all 0ms " + this.config.easing, this.sliderFrame.style.transition = "all 0ms " + this.config.easing
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "enableTransition",
                   value: function() {
                     this.sliderFrame.style.webkitTransition = "all " + this.config.duration + "ms " + this.config.easing, this.sliderFrame.style.transition = "all " + this.config.duration + "ms " + this.config.easing
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "goTo",
                   value: function(e, t) {
                     if (!(this.innerElements.length <= this.perPage)) {
                       var i = this.currentSlide;
                       this.currentSlide = this.config.loop ? e % this.innerElements.length : Math.min(Math.max(e, 0), this.innerElements.length - this.perPage), i !== this.currentSlide && (this.slideToCurrent(), this.config.onChange.call(this), t && t.call(this))
                     }
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "slideToCurrent",
                   value: function(e) {
                     var t = this,
                       i = this.config.loop ? this.currentSlide + this.perPage : this.currentSlide,
                       r = (this.config.rtl ? 1 : -1) * i * (this.selectorWidth / this.perPage);
                     e ? requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                       requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                         t.enableTransition(), t.sliderFrame.style[t.transformProperty] = "translate3d(" + r + "px, 0, 0)"
                       })
                     }) : this.sliderFrame.style[this.transformProperty] = "translate3d(" + r + "px, 0, 0)"
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "updateAfterDrag",
                   value: function() {
                     var e = (this.config.rtl ? -1 : 1) * (this.drag.endX - this.drag.startX),
                       t = Math.abs(e),
                       i = this.config.multipleDrag ? Math.ceil(t / (this.selectorWidth / this.perPage)) : 1,
                       r = e > 0 && this.currentSlide - i < 0,
                       n = e < 0 && this.currentSlide + i > this.innerElements.length - this.perPage;
                     e > 0 && t > this.config.threshold && this.innerElements.length > this.perPage ? this.prev(i) : e < 0 && t > this.config.threshold && this.innerElements.length > this.perPage && this.next(i), this.slideToCurrent(r || n)
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "resizeHandler",
                   value: function() {
                     this.resolveSlidesNumber(), this.currentSlide + this.perPage > this.innerElements.length && (this.currentSlide = this.innerElements.length <= this.perPage ? 0 : this.innerElements.length - this.perPage), this.selectorWidth = this.selector.offsetWidth, this.buildSliderFrame()
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "clearDrag",
                   value: function() {
                     this.drag = {
                       startX: 0,
                       endX: 0,
                       startY: 0,
                       letItGo: null,
                       preventClick: this.drag.preventClick
                     }
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "touchstartHandler",
                   value: function(e) {
                     -1 !== ["TEXTAREA", "OPTION", "INPUT", "SELECT"].indexOf(e.target.nodeName) || (e.stopPropagation(), this.pointerDown = !0, this.drag.startX = e.touches[0].pageX, this.drag.startY = e.touches[0].pageY)
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "touchendHandler",
                   value: function(e) {
                     e.stopPropagation(), this.pointerDown = !1, this.enableTransition(), this.drag.endX && this.updateAfterDrag(), this.clearDrag()
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "touchmoveHandler",
                   value: function(e) {
                     if (e.stopPropagation(), null === this.drag.letItGo && (this.drag.letItGo = Math.abs(this.drag.startY - e.touches[0].pageY) < Math.abs(this.drag.startX - e.touches[0].pageX)), this.pointerDown && this.drag.letItGo) {
                       e.preventDefault(), this.drag.endX = e.touches[0].pageX, this.sliderFrame.style.webkitTransition = "all 0ms " + this.config.easing, this.sliderFrame.style.transition = "all 0ms " + this.config.easing;
                       var t = this.config.loop ? this.currentSlide + this.perPage : this.currentSlide,
                         i = t * (this.selectorWidth / this.perPage),
                         r = this.drag.endX - this.drag.startX,
                         n = this.config.rtl ? i + r : i - r;
                       this.sliderFrame.style[this.transformProperty] = "translate3d(" + (this.config.rtl ? 1 : -1) * n + "px, 0, 0)"
                     }
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "mousedownHandler",
                   value: function(e) {
                     -1 !== ["TEXTAREA", "OPTION", "INPUT", "SELECT"].indexOf(e.target.nodeName) || (e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation(), this.pointerDown = !0, this.drag.startX = e.pageX)
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "mouseupHandler",
                   value: function(e) {
                     e.stopPropagation(), this.pointerDown = !1, this.selector.style.cursor = "-webkit-grab", this.enableTransition(), this.drag.endX && this.updateAfterDrag(), this.clearDrag()
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "mousemoveHandler",
                   value: function(e) {
                     if (e.preventDefault(), this.pointerDown) {
                       "A" === e.target.nodeName && (this.drag.preventClick = !0), this.drag.endX = e.pageX, this.selector.style.cursor = "-webkit-grabbing", this.sliderFrame.style.webkitTransition = "all 0ms " + this.config.easing, this.sliderFrame.style.transition = "all 0ms " + this.config.easing;
                       var t = this.config.loop ? this.currentSlide + this.perPage : this.currentSlide,
                         i = t * (this.selectorWidth / this.perPage),
                         r = this.drag.endX - this.drag.startX,
                         n = this.config.rtl ? i + r : i - r;
                       this.sliderFrame.style[this.transformProperty] = "translate3d(" + (this.config.rtl ? 1 : -1) * n + "px, 0, 0)"
                     }
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "mouseleaveHandler",
                   value: function(e) {
                     this.pointerDown && (this.pointerDown = !1, this.selector.style.cursor = "-webkit-grab", this.drag.endX = e.pageX, this.drag.preventClick = !1, this.enableTransition(), this.updateAfterDrag(), this.clearDrag())
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "clickHandler",
                   value: function(e) {
                     this.drag.preventClick && e.preventDefault(), this.drag.preventClick = !1
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "remove",
                   value: function(e, t) {
                     if (e < 0 || e >= this.innerElements.length) throw new Error("Item to remove doesn't exist ");
                     var i = e < this.currentSlide,
                       r = this.currentSlide + this.perPage - 1 === e;
                     (i || r) && this.currentSlide--, this.innerElements.splice(e, 1), this.buildSliderFrame(), t && t.call(this)
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "insert",
                   value: function(e, t, i) {
                     if (t < 0 || t > this.innerElements.length + 1) throw new Error("Unable to inset it at this index ");
                     if (-1 !== this.innerElements.indexOf(e)) throw new Error("The same item in a carousel? Really? Nope ");
                     var r = t <= this.currentSlide > 0 && this.innerElements.length;
                     this.currentSlide = r ? this.currentSlide + 1 : this.currentSlide, this.innerElements.splice(t, 0, e), this.buildSliderFrame(), i && i.call(this)
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "prepend",
                   value: function(e, t) {
                     this.insert(e, 0), t && t.call(this)
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "append",
                   value: function(e, t) {
                     this.insert(e, this.innerElements.length + 1), t && t.call(this)
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "destroy",
                   value: function() {
                     var e = arguments.length > 0 && void 0 !== arguments[0] && arguments[0],
                       t = arguments[1];
                     if (this.detachEvents(), this.selector.style.cursor = "auto", e) {
                       for (var i = document.createDocumentFragment(), r = 0; r < this.innerElements.length; r++) i.appendChild(this.innerElements[r]);
                       this.selector.innerHTML = "", this.selector.appendChild(i), this.selector.removeAttribute("style")
                     }
                     t && t.call(this)
                   }
                 }], [{
                   key: "mergeSettings",
                   value: function(e) {
                     var t = {
                         selector: ".siema",
                         duration: 200,
                         easing: "ease-out",
                         perPage: 1,
                         startIndex: 0,
                         draggable: !0,
                         multipleDrag: !0,
                         threshold: 20,
                         loop: !1,
                         rtl: !1,
                         onInit: function() {},
                         onChange: function() {}
                       },
                       i = e;
                     for (var r in i) t[r] = i[r];
                     return t
                   }
                 }, {
                   key: "webkitOrNot",
                   value: function() {
                     return "string" == typeof document.documentElement.style.transform ? "transform" : "WebkitTransform"
                   }
                 }]), e
               }();
             t.default = l, e.exports = t.default
           }])
         });
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.carousel .-arrow {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: 15px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.carousel .-arrow._left {
  left: 25px;
}

.carousel .-arrow._right {
  right: 25px;
}

.carousel .-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel .-dot {
  border: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel .-dot._active {
  background-color: gray;
}

.carousel .-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel._small {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.carousel._small .-img {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.carousel._small .-arrows {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel._small .-arrow {
  margin: 25px 10px;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel" class="carousel _small">
  <div class="-inner">
    <img class="-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    <img class="-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    <img class="-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    <img class="-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    <img class="-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    <img class="-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    <img class="-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    <img class="-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    <img class="-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    <img class="-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="-arrows">
    <div class="-arrow _left"></div>
    <div class="-arrow _right"></div>
    <div class="-dots"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```